# Redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS duplicates the www

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

I'm trying to redirect the user to `https://www.example.com`, when the user tries `http://example.com`, `www.example.com`, `https://example.com`, `http://www.example.com` etc.

For that I use this code in my `.htaccess`-file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

The problem with this is that when the user types in `www.example.com` or `http://www.example.com`, the user will then be redirected to `https://www.www.example.com`. In other words, it duplicates the www.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: To those that closed this... I understand how this _might_ be considered 'to localized', however, I'm not sure why it is 'off topic'?

Comment: It is not off topic or localized. Might be *duplicated* as there are dozens of similar questions, NOT CLOSED, by the way. In this case, it is just non-sense, as it is happening here very often unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:www\.)?(.*)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Nice way to make sure the `www` is always there. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This uses apache to get the host and doesn't rely on it for the redirect, and will also keep the requested URI using apache as well. ^^ (without having to use anything actually matches in the `RewriteRule`)

Comment: Yay! That got rid of the www duplication, but when entering the site via. `http://example.com` it only gets redirected to `https://example.com`. I need the domain to always be `https://www.example.com`. Thanks for the quick respond, Jon :-)

Comment: No problem!  Sorry, I misread the first part of always requiring the `www`. ^^